# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb) Outlets fully connected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, action, iboutlet

I am getting

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb)

My outlets and actions are fully connected. There is no yellow exclamation mark by any of the outlets. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste your console log here

Comment: Thats part of the issue all i get is: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: this issue happen at what point any specific change that you make in your project ?

Comment: Maybe there is more than one outlet to the same element.

Comment: Also go in the debug session when your code crashes...It is the 6th tab from the extreme left from where you navigate your project..You crashed line code will be the top one..from here you can see exactly where your code crashed.

Comment: I have got same error while changing orientation of particular screen , but my app only supports portrait! this occurred only in iOS 11 .you can check description by adding Exception breakpoint and using command $arg1.

Comment: It happened after I tried adding a search bar.

Comment: @Ishika I got an error message but it doesnt tell me exactly where, just random lines of code. Like this     0x18d16f880 <+208>: mov    x0, x20

Comment: Solved it! The issue was I was missing the storyboard and LaunchScreen storyboard in the Copy Bundle Resources section lol.